# recursividad con array's PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo una funcion (listarUrls()) que me devuelve/escanea todos las url's que encuentra en una página web.
            Necesito que por cada una de las url que la función me devuelve, vuelva a listar/escanear todas las url's de esa página.
            Y así tantas veces como pida el usuario, es decir: $arry

```
        .Si el usuario pide 1 iteración de la url www.a.com, el programa devuelve:
            -$arry[0] www.1.com
            -$arry[1] www.2.com
            -..... así con todas las url's que encuentre en www.a.com
         (este paso ya está hecho)

        .Si el usuario pide 2 iteraciones de la url www.a.com, el programa devuelve:
            -$arry[0] www.1.com
                -$arry[0][0] www.1-1.com
                -$arry[0][1] www.1-2.com
                -...así con todas las url's que encuentre en www.1.com
            -$arry[1] www.2.com
                -$arry[1][0] www.2-1.com
                -$arry[1][1] www.2-2.com
                -...así con todas las url's que encuentre en www.2.com
            -...lo mismo para el resto de casos

        .Si el usuario pide 3 iteraciones de la url www.a.com, el programa devuelve:
            -$arry[0] www.1.com
                -$arry[0][0] www.1-1.com
                    -$arry[0][0][0] www.1-1-1.com
                    -$arry[0][0][1] www.1-1-2.com
                    -...así con todas las url's que encuentre en www.1-1.com
                -$arry[0][1] www.1-2.com
                    -$arry[0][1][0] www.1-2-1.com
                    -$arry[0][1][1] www.1-2-2.com
                    -...así con todas las url's que encuentre en www.1-2.com
            -$arry[1] www.2.com
                -$arry[1][0] www.2-1.com
                    -$arry[1][0][0] www.2-1-1.com
                    -$arry[1][0][1] www.2-1-2.com
                    -...así con todas las url's que encuentre en www.2-1.com
                -$arry[1][1] www.2-2.com
                    -$arry[1][1][0] www.2-2-1.com
                    -$arry[1][1][1] www.2-2-2.com
                    -...así con todas las url's que encuentre en www.2-2.com
        -...lo mismo para el resto de casos
```

Alguien podría arrojarme algo de luz sobre el tema por favor?

Comment: parece que es un problema de recursividad. Vas a tener que hacer una funcion a la que le pases dos parametros (la url y el nivel de profundidad). Primero miras que el nivel sea distinto de 0. si es asi que haga el analisis de las urls que tenga. Si ese analisis te devuelve vacio, devuelve null. Sino, haces un bucle por cada url, asignando a cada item el resultado de llamando a la misma funcion de forma recursiva, con el nivel-1.

Comment: Podrías darme un ejemplo de la función recursiva? me estoy liando con los foreach/for y los niveles.

Comment: PHP tiene también una interfaz [`Iterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.iterator.php) y [varias clases para iteradores](https://www.php.net/manual/es/spl.iterators.php) que podrían ser útiles para casos como este, por ejemplo [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).